# python output of selenium IDE, should it run in console or only in IDE?

Tags: python, selenium

I created and saved a browser test using selenium IDE in firefox.

It has a export feature, and I saved the python code.

Should it work in console also, i.e:

```
python selenium_test.py
```

Because I get this error:

```
Errno 10061 no connection could be made becasue the target machine actively refused it.
```

selenium is working fine when I create the python script, I was hoping I could use the IDE then spit out python and then tweak it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to download and run the Selenium RC server. The script you have generated from the IDE is trying to connect to it, probably on a certain port on localhost, so run the server on that port.

Comment: is the selenium server RC ok to run on a dev computer for local testing?

Comment: btw, if I open the IDE in firefox, I can't seem to run a previous file that I saved and exported.  the run icon is greyed out, why?

Comment: Yes, Selenium RC is just a JAR file. You run it to start the server. Your Python/Ruby/etc script connects to Selenium RC which does all the actual work (starting a browser, executing all the actions). No problem in running it on a dev machine. As for your second question, I'm not sure, sorry. Are you trying to load the python script, because I'm not sure that's possible with the IDE.